# Sending emails from sales or service cloud or sending through marketing cloud.

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Sending emails from sales or service cloud using Marketing cloud connector or sending through marketing cloud, Which will take more time or there will be no time lag as the sending vehicle is still Marketing cloud in both the cases.